# Linux CC compiling error

Tags: cc

I'm trying to compile a program with the CC compiler, but when running the command in Terminal:

```
cc –o sm hw33.c random.c stopwatch.c –lm
```

I get this error:

```
cc: error: –o: No such file or directory
cc: error: sm: No such file or directory
cc: error: –lm: No such file or directory
```

All the files exist and the names are indeed correct.

What seems to be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The `–` characters in your post aren't `-` characters.  I copy/pasted one and ran it through `hexdump`:

```
$ pbpaste | hexdump -vC
00000000  e2 80 93                                          |...|
00000003
```

Breaking down those bytes in binary gives:

```
11100010 10000000 10010011
```

And extracting the unicode code point from them by matching up with the 16-bit code point entry in [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description):

```
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

Yields:

```
    0010   000000   010011  --->  0010 0000 0010 0011
```

Turning that back to hex gives code point 0x2013, which is "EN DASH" according to [this unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf).

How did you type it?  You need an ASCII/UTF-8 `-` (code point 0x2d, "HYPHEN-MINUS") for the compiler to be able to handle it.

Comment: [eagleye!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754051/297323)

Comment: Thanks @FredrikPihl, but I just guessed based on the error messages and happened to be proven right.